# Appropriate reply if someone asks you are good at something?

Tags: american-english, sentence-choice

Someone asks you - **Are you good at biology?**

As a tutor following replies come to my mind :

> 1. I am not into it.
> 2. I don't tutor biology
> 3. That's not my area of expertise

Which of the above are correct?
Any better way to reply back?

Comment: *I'm afraid not.*

Answer (score 1):

> I am not into it.

That is quite informal and I suspect would mostly be used by younger people

> I don't tutor biology

That is grammatical but does not really answer the question "Are you good at biology" as you could be brilliant at it but not tutor it.

> That's not my area of expertise

That is perfectly fine but quite formal. You would be more likely to use it in writing.

And as @Void mentioned in comments

> I'm afraid not

is a very common and correct usage.

Comment: Regarding the sentence - I'm afraid not. If I look in dictionary the meaning for afraid is like - worried, anxious. How does it fits here. If we take the literal meaning of afraid then the sentence I'm afraid not , sounds like I'm worried.

Comment: It is commonly used in the sense of worried or sorry. An alternative would been to have just replied "Sorry". It does not in this context carry the sense of fear.